# Windows 10 Проводник. Сортировка папок и файлов вместе

Tags: windows-10

Есть 2 файла и одна папка
Файлы:

```
"1"
"3"
```

Папка:

```
"2"
```

И их сортировка в результате даёт

```
"1"
"3"
"2"
```

или

```
"2"
"1"
"3"
```

Как заставить именно дефолтный Проводник сортировать как надо?

5 лет назад не компьютере с Win7 всё сортировалось нормально.

Comment: Видимо, это невозможно. 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-desegregate-foldersfiles-in-file-explorer/ccc004c5-0c39-4911-a5e7-82609106570d

Comment: Можно использовать сторонний файловый менеджер https://superuser.com/a/902272/1106749

Comment: It seems that Windows doesn't have that sorting option yet. Это обман, на Win7 это точно возможно.

Comment: Не уверен. В этом вопросе https://superuser.com/questions/204016/windows-explorer-sorts-files-and-folders-separately речь именно про windows 7.